# What happens if you beat Cassiopeia the second time?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

In the game "Ni No Kuni", after beating Cassiopeia (and the second version, and the council guy), you see a lot of credits and you unlock the post ending stuff. I randomly entered the room afterwards and she's still there and I can fight her again. What happens when you beat her a second time? Is the sequence the same (witch, second version, council guy)? Are there more credits or do you just end up in the room where the battle was in? Can you beat her a third time?

Comment: I think I recall battling a more powerful version of the final boss when I went in the second time. I think you just do the same  battle over and over again for furhter tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a "cleared" save game, you're taken back to a point just before you start fighting Cassiopeia the first time.  If you go to her chambers again, you'll fight her again just like you did the first time.  Talking to any NPCs will reveal that they're still waiting for you to get on with the final fight already.

There is a harder version of the final version of the fight that you can find by:

> running the post-game errands.  By assisting the man who lost his diary a final time in Ding Dong Dell, you'll meet the Conductor, who will send you across the world to fight harder versions of all the bosses.  One of these is the third form of the final boss, which takes place at Ara Memorae, and not in the queen's chambers in the Ivory Tower.

Comment: So beating her the second time just leaves you in the Ivory Tower? And you can't fight her a third time?

Comment: You can fight her as many times as you want. But she is just a way of getting the ending. The fight isn't really relevant after beating her the first time.

Comment: @JonLin, yes, what Reafexus said is correct.  Beating her and loading a cleared save essentially just rewinds game time to before the fight.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not worth fighting through again. Experience is not worth it, 9,800. Takes less time to farm tokotokos for the same amount of experience, 9,000,  or fight Guardian of the Worlds, 28,000, for more then tokocolds, 26,000 . Plus you have to sit through the final animation again and credits.

Tokotoko - 9,000 - Farm Spawns Perdida

The White Witch - 9,800 - Always There @Ivory Tower (3 stages & Animations & Credits)

Tokocold - 26,000 - Farm Spawns Ivory Tower

Guardian of the Worlds - 28,000 - Always There @Gate (1 Stage)